# Table relationship issue in database design

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design, relational-database

I have Payrollsalary tables

```
PayrollSalaryMaster (PayrollID,PayMonth,EmployeeID)
PayrollSalaryDetail (DetailID,PayrollID,ComponentID,Amount)
```

I have Amendment table that record the amendments in salary if there is deviation form approved salary

```
PayAmmendments (AmendmentID,Detailid,Amount)
```

Now I have new requirement that Employee Salary's or any of its component can be Hold (i.e.) It will not be paid with the current salary. I modified the PayAmmendments table as

```
PayAmmendments (AmendmentID,Detailid,Amount,IsHold)
```

**Question**
Now if some Employee's whole salary is put on hold how to handle is scenario in above design

Comment: Whats the problem of your design.

Comment: I wouldn't even have table `PayAmmendments`. Why not store each line item in `PayrollSalaryDetail`? When you query month worth of salary [lets call it transaction] transactions, you just call it in sequence in which they entered into `PayrollSalaryDetail`. You can create lookup table `PayrollSalaryDetailType` and add corresponding column to `PayrollSalaryDetail`. And just keep adding details.

Comment: @T.S I am storing each line in PayrollSalaryDetail. I am creating table of amendment to keep track what changes are made in pay.

Comment: Your question is not clear. You ask how "to handle". What does that mean? Your description is also not clear. Does "any of its component can" be Held (or be on Hold or have a Hold) maybe mean that any component can be held, or maybe that any part of a component's amount can be held (up to the total amount), or what--because why is Amount in PayAmendments? Also what does "an Employee's Salary can" be Held mean--Per PayrollId? Per Employee, from now on? Is it all Held or not, or can some Amount be held? Explain, don't just use one word "handle" or "Held" that only you understand.

Comment: This is exactly what I am saying, why do amendment table, if detail table can be history itself. All you need to do is have a flag on the record to see if it is active, or whatever. Basically, don't ever post `update or delete` to your `PayrollSalaryDetail`, only `Insert`. Although, you will update only one column - the flag column, which will tell status of the record, e.g. `Revised`

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is right, you can probably save the data as follows:

**PayrollSalaryMaster**:

```
PayrollID  |  PayMonth  | EmployeeID
PAYROLL1   |  JULY      | E123
```

**PayrollSalaryDetail**

```
DetailID |  PayrollID  |  ComponentID  | Amount
DET1     |  PAYROLL1   |  COMP1        | 0
```

**PayAmmendments**

```
AmendmentID   |  Detailid  |  Amount |  IsHold
AM1           |  DET1      |  0      |  TRUE
```

*If the employee's salary is 5000, may be you can also try the following based on your scenario*

**PayrollSalaryDetail**

```
DetailID |  PayrollID  |  ComponentID  | Amount
DET1     |  PAYROLL1   |  COMP1        | 5000
```

**PayAmmendments**

```
AmendmentID   |  Detailid  |  Amount |  IsHold
AM1           |  DET1      |  -5000  |  TRUE
```

Comment: In your design relationship issue is resolved through data. which may not scale e.g. some component may be variable say loan deduction

Comment: Or you are trying to say that I should add all the component in amendment table with hold

Comment: Assume 2000 for loan and 3000 for others is deducted, can't you have payAmendments as AM1 | LOAN | -2000 | TRUE and AM2 | OTHERS | -3000 | TRUE?

Comment: yes that solution is there but I am looking for a better solution so that for whole salary on hold I don't have to add each component in amendment. Moreover it will make amendment table Master-Detail

Answer (score 0):

I think to hold column will set in master, not in ammendment.

The reason is you hold the whole salary of employee, not only ammendment. Also this is usefull, when you want to show onhold salary record for particular month.

Yes, good to add "IsHold" Column in ammendment table, in case your company decide to hold only arrear after declaration of particular employee(s), not whole salary.